# PHP ssh2_auth_pubkey_file not working with encrypted private key

Tags: php, sftp, libssh2

I am using ssh2 in PHP, as follows:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $username, $pubKey, $privKey, $passphrase);
```

This results in the error message:

```
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for username using public key
```

I am however, able to connect fine by using sftp directly in a terminal.

```
$ sftp -oPort=PORT -i /path/to/private/key USER@HOST
```

(The sftp command responds to ask for the passphrase, and it then connects.)

I'm at a bit of a loss with debugging this - the ssh2 commands are asking for and being provided with all the relevant information to connect, and I can connect fine using sftp directly in a terminal. What might the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up ditching ssh2 for [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

First, load the private key as follows:

```
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->setPassword($passphrase);
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents($keyPath));
```

Then login using the key:

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP($host, $port);
$loginResult = $sftp->login($username, $key);
```